# How to make a minipage the footer for a document

Tags: positioning, footer

I have a document that produces an output something like this:

[image]

The section in the green can change its size, depending on how many items are in the list.

I want the "Ship to:" and "Additional Information" sections to always be at the bottom of the page, no matter how big the green section is.

I am assuming that I need to do this by using footers? I have been reading about footers, but I'm not sure how to have the footer be a mini-page like this:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
        {\bf SHIP TO:}\\

        \textit{contact@commerciaJwaterheating.com}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        {\bf ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:}\\

        \textit{We accept payment by cash or cheque. Payment Is due upon receipt, and must be paid in full within {\bf 30 days}.}
\end{minipage}
```

---

THE ENTIRE TEX FILE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,currency=pound]{dapper-purchase_order}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Path = ./Fonts/ }
%\usepackage{fontawesome}                                                                                                                
\definecolor{Mblue}{RGB}{231,255,229}
%                                                                                                                                        
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% HEADING SECTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                                                                                    
\newcommand{\purchaseOrderNo}{31401} % Invoice Number                                                                                    
\newcommand{\Date}{01/01/2018} % Date                                                                                                    
\newcommand{\clientName}{CUSTOMER NAME LTD} % Client Name                                                                                
%----------------------------------------------------                                                                                    
%                                                                                                                                        
\begin{document}

\newfontface\mainLightItalic{OpenSans-LightItalic}
\makeheader{\purchaseOrderNo}

\addvspace{8ex}

{\Large DATE: \textit{\Date}}

\addvspace{2ex}

{\Large FOR: \textit{\clientName}}

\addvspace{4ex}

\hspace{-.9\marginparwidth}%                                                                                                             
\colorbox{Mblue}{\begin{minipage}{\paperwidth}%                                                                                          

\vspace{.3in}

\begin{hoursItemization}
%                                                                                                                                        
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TABLE OF EXPENSES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                                                                                  
%                                                                                                                                        
% Put your expenses here in this order: \lineitem{QTY}{PRICE}{ITEM}                                                                      
%                                                                                                                                        
    \lineitem{1}{3075}{550 Litre indirect Storage Vessel with Unvented Kit}
%                                                                                                                                        
    \lineitem{2}{214}{3 kW Aquarius Towel Rail Heating Element with Chrome Finish}
%                                                                                                                                        
    \lineitem{1}{225}{9 kW Stainless Steel Immersion Heater}
%------------------------------------------------------                                                                                  
%                                                                                                                                        
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SUMMARY SECTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                                                                                  
%                                                                                                                                        
    \beginsummary
%                                                                                                                                        
    \summaryline{SUBTOTAL}{\InvoiceTotal}
%                                                                                                                                        
    \summaryline{V.A.T. @ 20\%}{\vat}
%                                                                                                                                        
    \summaryline{TOTAL}{\total}
%------------------------------------------------------                                                                                  
%                                                                                                                                        
\end{hoursItemization}

\vspace{.3in}

\end{minipage}}

\addvspace{10ex}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
        {\bf SHIP TO:}\\

        \textit{contact@commerciaJwaterheating.com}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        {\bf ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:}\\

        \textit{We accept payment by cash or cheque. Payment Is due upon receipt, and must be paid in full within {\bf 30 days}.}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

(The class file is long - so I won't post as I don't think it is necessary to address the problem).

Comment: Are you aware of the `eso-pic` package (which would make most sense if this is a multi-page document), or the `\vfill` command? If you post  an MWE, people can give you more feedback.

Comment: Its only a single page. But won't the \vfill amount be different all the time if the middle part is changing its size?

Comment: Would something like this, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218242/two-logos-and-text-in-the-footer, help?  If not, why not?  (for example, my answer there has a `\parbox` and images in the footer)

Comment: @user1551817 Did you try marmots suggestion to `\vfill` (instead of `\addvspace{10ex}`)?

Comment: \vfill did work - sorry I misunderstood what it did. Thank you.

Comment: @marmot Sounds like you solved the problem. Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for notifying me!! Do you think this is the simplest solution? I mean if it is only one page, there are simpler ways, without eso-pic. But I will be happy to write something... in a few hours.

Comment: @marmot  A clean solution would put this in a footline, but I don't know which package to suggest for this without having the code of document class. On the other hand the code already involves a lot of manual spacing so I don't think `\vfill` does any harm :)

Comment: Off-topic: `\bf` is a few decades obsolete by now. Might be time to update that bit of your code while you're working on it.

Comment: A really nice solution here would require access to the class, as @samcarter says. And the class should ideally manage the routine stuff currently done in the document i.e. if you are always inserting `\vspace{.3in}` or `\hspace{-.9\marginparwidth}`, then it shouldn't be up to the end-user to get that right: the class should do it every time. (If these are one-off adjustments for this particular case, that's different, obviously.)

Comment: @user1551817: Where can we find `dapper-purchase_order.cls`?

Answer (score 5):

There are many options, the probably simplest being `\vfill`, which will push stuff to the bottom. Since I do not have your document class, I illustrate two options in a generic example. Further options include the `tikzpagenode` package, which makes the absolute positioning that comes with Ti*k*Z easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic} % only needed for the second option
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
First option: \verb|\vfill|
\vfill
Bottom--line: \verb|\vfill| works
\clearpage
Another option: use \texttt{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
     \AtTextUpperLeft{%
         \put(0,-500){\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
         Bottom--line: also works. you may want to adjust the
         $y$ value \texttt{500} to your needs. This option is particularly useful if
         you want to write many pages with the same bottom--line.
         \end{minipage}}%
     }%
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way the behaviour you want can be achived, without using footers, is by adding a vspace combined with a strecth factor.

Adding `\vspace*{\stretch{2}}` before your two minipages with **Ship to** and **Additional Info.**, pushes them to the bottom of the page. The command will ajust the vertical space according to the content added above.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\vspace*{\stretch{2}}` or `\vspace*{\stretch{1}}` (more simply `\vspace*{\fill}`) would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem that I saw in your footer is that it doesn't accept paragraphs. In your case, this is easy to solve with `\\[<length>]` because you have fixed content there. I used the `fancyhdr` package  in my MWE, however I had to remove your private things since we don't have access to it. See below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

%% geometry package was used to build a page that was similar to yours
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry}

%% lipsum to create filler text 
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%% set the footer
\cfoot{
  % \begin{tabular}{p{\linewidth}}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
    {\bf SHIP TO:}\\[1mm] %% <- changed here
    \textit{contact@commerciaJwaterheating.com}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    {\bf ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:}\\[1mm] %% <- changed here    
    \textit{We accept payment by cash or cheque. Payment Is due upon receipt, and must be paid in full within {\bf 30 days}.}
  \end{minipage}
}

%% remove the top line, which is default in fancyhdr
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: mwe]

This also use `fancyhdr`, but allow a central number of page below. (Just for fun, without tikz, tabular nor minipages).

Note: `\bf` is a deprecated command. Use  `{\bfseries ...}` or `\textbf{...}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,bmargin=6cm,footskip=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\lfoot{\leavevmode
\vbox to 20ex{\hsize.6\linewidth{\bfseries SHIP TO:}\\[1ex]\itshape
contact@commerciaJwaterheating.com}%
\vbox to 20ex{\hsize.4\linewidth {\bfseries 
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:}\\[1ex]\normalfont\itshape
We accept payment by cash or cheque. Payment is due upon receipt, 
and must be paid in full within {\bfseries 30 days}.}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```